# Is external API call allowed in Microsoft Exhange Add-In Development?

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-addin

I need to develop an Add-in for Outlook for a Microsoft Exchange Server. The add-in has to communicate with an external API other than the Microsoft API. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can develop your own service which can perform some tasks on behalf of the add-in. See [Create a web service for an app for Office using the ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/officeapps/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api)

When making calls outside the domain your add-in is hosted in, you need to specify those domains in your add-in's manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://mysite1.yourdomain.net/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://mysite2.yourdomain.net/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

You may also find the [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article.